# how to use one Frame buffer object to both render on texture2d and render on screen in opengles 2.x ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to record everything in my game( using opengles ) into movie to user could replay later.
I have problem is:
I used frame buffer to render on texture2d and get read pixel from it using `CVPixelBuffer` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` to record movie. But when i did that, my game was not running anymore. I think because frame buffer wasn't render to `colorRenderBuffer`, I added this line after record movie

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
```

After using this, game was running normally but movie is black.
So I wonder how to use one Frame buffer object to both render on texture2d and render on screen in opengles 2.x ios.

If anybody has any idea for resolve this problem, please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ordinarily you would use `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` to do this, but OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support this. Your best bet would be to attach a frame buffer texture to your FBO, then draw a quad that covers your entire screen and displays this texture.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try to do it now.